# Why does sending this 9-bit command to barcode scanning module via UART from Raspberry Pi 3 fail?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, barcode-scanner

I am trying to communicate between a Raspberry Pi 3 and barcode scanner by Waveshare via a UART command, but I always receive a blank response. The command is 9-bits long, which might be the issue. I also noticed after printing the `scanning_command` , that the first bit is ignored...?

Following the barcode scanner's [documentation](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/d/dd/Barcode_Scanner_Module_Setting_Manual_EN.pdf) I've tried several varying python scripts to run the command, but always receive the serial output `b''`. I am not experienced with Raspberry Pi and would appreciate any help.

Script:

```
import serial

# Define the serial port and baud rate
serial_port = '/dev/ttyS0'
baud_rate = 9600

# Define the scanning command
scanning_command = b'\x7E\x00\x08\x01\x00\x02\x01\xAB\xCD'  

# Open the serial connection
ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate)

# Send the scanning command
ser.write(scanning_command)

response = ser.read(7)  # Read 7 bytes response
print("Response:", response.hex())
```

Comment: It appears that this scanner defaults to the USB interface, rather than UART.  You can configure this by scanning special codes from the user's manual - "Open Setting Code Function" followed by "UART Output".

Comment: I set the scanner to `POS mode`, which sets it to command mode and UART output.

Comment: Please use the correct words. It's a `byte`, not a `bit`.

Comment: You possibly have to add a Carriage Return `\x0D` or a Line Feed `\x0A`, or both, to the end of the command you send.